# Is a high speed or low speed water droplet colder when it hits the floor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, temperature

I have two water droplets, about 2mm across, one with an initial velocity of $4ms^{-1}$ towards the ground, which is 5 metres away. The other has an initial velocity of $0ms^{-1}$. Both have an average temperature of 50°C.

I'm not sure how I can calculate the energy lost to air resistance, and how much of this energy is lost as a reduction in acceleration, and how much is a reduction in temperature.

I've calculated the speeds when the drop hits the floor assuming there is no air resistance:

[image]

Which droplet is colder? (This is not a homework question).

Comment: It may not be a homework question but it is formulated like one and you have shown no effort to tackle the problem. Voting to close.

Comment: @JamalS I've got some calculations- would a photograph of those be suitable?

Comment: No, you need to write it up, preferably using LateX.

Comment: @JamalS I'm on mobile - latex is shockingly difficult to type. Why is a photograph unsuitable?

Comment: @Tim: E.g. because text in pics are not searchable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does water get significantly colder while falling through the air?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205624/why-does-water-get-significantly-colder-while-falling-through-the-air)

Comment: @sammygerbil no, I'm asking which is cooler. Not why they're cooler! They're cooler because of air resistance...

Comment: I think it's a good qustion. It is well-defined and non-trivial. It's not a duplicate of the suggested since it is quantitative and specific rather than "generally-speaking". If you'll find the time to format it properly and show an attempt to find the heat loss, you should attract better responses. I'd actually like to know the answer myself.

Comment: You have shown some effort to calculate the *speed* at which the drops reach the ground. But how do you think this affects the answer to your question? The question I cited asks *What is a good mathematical and thermodynamic model for explaining the temperature change of falling water?* Without such a model it is difficult to make a calculated prediction. Even a qualitative answer is difficult : it is not obvious whether the faster droplet gains more heat from friction than it loses from evaporation.

Comment: @sammygerbil well that's part of my question - does it gain or lose - either could. does the slower one lose more because it's in the air longer or less because it's slower.